# Render is called twice when fetching data from a REST API

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to interact with a REST API using React, and I have realized that when I fetch the data, `render` is called once **without the data**, and then again **with** the data.

This throws an exception when I try to process this data, but I can use an if statement to check if data is null or not. However, I am not sure if that's needed.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    TodoList: {},
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5001/1").then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        TodoList: response.data,
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return <h1>hello </h1>;
  }
}
```

This is what I see in in the console:
[image]

Comment: If you ever feel confused why the render method is called twice or more number of times, you can use React's Profiler API - https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html

React's Profiler is really helpful in making your react component's performance better.

Comment: I would recommend to carefully read trough the React.js-official documentation so you get familiar with how things work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**That's perfectly normal.**

Your `App` component flow as below:

1. Execute `render` method to load the component
2. execute codes in `componentDidMount`
3. Calling `axios.get` which is async operation
4. Receive data from step 2, update component state by using `this.setState`
5. `App` component detected there's an update on state, hence execute `render` method to load component again

Hence, you should definitely handle the case where `this.state.TodoList` has no data, which happened at first load

**UPDATES:**

component lifecycle `componentWillMount` is now deprecated which means you shouldn't be using it anymore. Replace it with `componentDidMount` instead. Functionally wise they should be no difference in your example

Comment: I created a function which evaluates `if (this.state.TodoList)` and returns object based on condition.

Answer (score 1):

1. Initially, render method is called after cwm method. So console log shows the state's empty value first time.
2. But you have run an async operation in cwm method, so after it is done, the setstate method is called which causes the render method to run again.

Note: ComponentWillMount, componentWillUpdate and componentWillUpdate props method are deprecated.

You should move this API call to componentDidmount or ComponentDidUpdate method.

However, event after this, your console log will appear twice- one for initial render and second for setstate called after API call.

Answer (score 0):

**Note : `componentWillMount` is deprecated and will work until version 17.**

Source - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

**Most suitable React Lifecycle for calling APIs:**
`componentDidMount` is the most prefered method to perform asynchronous tasks like API calls, setTimeouts , etc..

It'll work as -

1. On `componentDidMount` your API gets called
2. As per lifecycle order, lastly render method will be called. (Still API hasn't returned response). Your UI is displayed at initial paint.
3. Once API gets response, you use `this.setState()` which will force a re-render operation.
4. Again your UI changes are updated

Remember : `this.setState()` will only be called once whether you have called it once or more than once in lifecycle method