# React Context api, I can't get to object from context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I started to learn React, I'm trying to retrieve data from api, the data is an object with the fields of `base, date & rates`, without any problem I can print and logout `base & date` but `rates` which is an object not.

console.log gives undefined, when trying to iterate is obviously that the object does not exist but in DevTools i can see normal data

Thank you for your help and greetings

Context:

```
export const ExchangeProvider = props => {
const [lastestExchanges, setLastestExchanges] = useState({})

const fetchLastestExchange = async () => {
    try {
        await fetch(`https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest`).then(data => data.json()).then(data => setLastestExchanges(data))
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchLastestExchange()
}, [])

return (
    <ExchangeContext.Provider value={[lastestExchanges, setLastestExchanges]}>
        {props.children}
    </ExchangeContext.Provider>
)
}
```

Usage:

```
import React, {useState, useContext} from "react";
import {ExchangeContext} from "../ExchangeContext";

function HomeView() {
    const [lastestExchange, setLastestExchange] = useContext(ExchangeContext)
    console.log(lastestExchange)
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <p>{lastestExchange.base}</p>
            <p>{lastestExchange.date}</p>
            {/*<p>{lastestExchange.rates['PLN']}</p>*/}
            <ul>
                {/*{Object.keys(lastestExchange.rates).map(key => <li>{lastestExchange.rates[key]}</li>)}*/}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default HomeView
```

Provider usage:

```
import React from 'react';
import HomeView from "./Views/HomeView";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import {ExchangeProvider} from "./ExchangeContext";

function App() {
    return (
        <ExchangeProvider>
            <div className="App container w-full flex h-full">
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/">
                            <HomeView/>
                        </Route>
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </div>
        </ExchangeProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please also show how you use `ExchangeProvider`. Do you see two `console.log()´s from HomeView?

Comment: Yes, i ll show you in 2 minutes

Comment: Im added to main post

Comment: Are you sure there aren't two console.logs from the function? By "in devtools I see normal data" - are you referring to React devtools? If so, which component shows that? If you look at HomeView and its context value, what does it show? Are there errors?

Comment: Yes, there are two console logs from HomeView, one is empty object, second is normal data ( normal data means what I expect there to be ). 

When i `console.log(lastestExchange)` `rates` are there but `console.log(lastestExchange.rates)` is undefined.

Comment: I think i know why, i just try to get value by key from empty object, so i need to learn how to call it when fetch is complete

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render is called twice when fetching data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54384871/render-is-called-twice-when-fetching-data-from-a-rest-api)

Comment: how do you export the actual context itself ?, in your context file ?

Comment: Yes, `export const ExchangeContext = createContext();`

Comment: ok, I need to check if `rates` exist and now works, thanks everyone

Answer (score -1):

You can use react context simpler like this :

```
// src/ThemeContext.js
 
import React from 'react';
 
const ThemeContext = React.createContext(null);
 
export default ThemeContext;
```

```
// src/ComponentA.js
 
import React from 'react';
import ThemeContext from './ThemeContext';
 
const A = () => (
  <ThemeContext.Provider value="green">
    <D />
  </ThemeContext.Provider>
);
```

```
// src/ComponentD.js
 
import React from 'react';
import ThemeContext from './ThemeContext';
 
const D = () => (
  <ThemeContext.Consumer>
    {value => (
      <p style={{ color: value }}>
        Hello World
      </p>
    )}
  </ThemeContext.Consumer>
);
```